# Reconnect a disconnected video element audio node

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, web-audio-api, mediarecorder

I am recording a canvas stream (streamA) which contains video frames exported from a video element and imported into the outputcanvas element.

```
var video = document.createElement("VIDEO");
video.src = "test.mp4";

var outputcanvas = document.createElement("CANVAS");
outputcanvas.width = 1920; 
outputcanvas.height = 1080;
var ctx = outputcanvas.getContext("2d");

var streamA = outputcanvas.captureStream(60);
```

I then use web audio api to connect the video audio to the stream

```
var source; 
var dest;
var getContext = function() {
  var ac = null;
  if ( !window.AudioContext && !window.webkitAudioContext ) {
    console.warn('Web Audio API not supported in this browser');
  } else {
    ac = new ( window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext )();
  }
  return function() {
    return ac;
  };
}();
var audioCtx = getContext();        
source = source || audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(video);            
dest = dest || audioCtx.createMediaStreamDestination();         
source.connect(dest);
var audioTrack = dest.stream.getAudioTracks();
streamA.addTrack(audioTrack[0]);

video.play(); //this is inside a request animation so each frame is copied to the canvas
ctx.drawImage(video,0,0,outputcanvas.width,outputcanvas.height);
```

Everything works great, and I can output the recorded video and audio fine to an mp4.

The problem I get is after I have recorded the video and reset the stream.

The audio node of the video element has been disconnected.

Is there an easy way I can just reconnect it back? because the video in the video element wont even play anymore unless I mute it.

Answer (score 2):

That's indeed a big flow with the `createMediaElementSource` API, the element can not retrieve its graph back.

This won't be fixed, because nowadays there is a better way to connect an HTMLMediaElement to the AudioContext: `HTMLMediaElement.captureStream`.
You could create a MediaStreamSource from the returned MediaStream, but in your case you don't even need an AudioContext anymore, just get the audio track directly:

```js
const vid_url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/Volcano_Lava_Sample.webm";
const video = document.createElement("video");
video.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
video.src = vid_url;
document.body.append(video);
video.controls = true;
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
let recording = false;
btn.onclick = async (evt) => {
  await video.play();
  canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
  canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
  ctx.filter = "invert(1)";
  const vid_stream = (video.captureStream ? video.captureStream() : video.mozCaptureStream());
  const audio_track = vid_stream.getAudioTracks()[0];
  vid_stream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop(); // no need to keep capturing video
  
  recording = true;
  drawToCanvas();
  const canvas_track = canvas.captureStream().getVideoTracks()[0];
  const merged_stream = new MediaStream([canvas_track, audio_track]);
  const chunks = [];
  const recorder = new MediaRecorder(merged_stream);
  recorder.ondataavailable = ({ data }) => chunks.push(data);
  recorder.onstop = (evt) => {
    exportVid( chunks );
    audio_track.stop();
    canvas_track.stop();
    recording = false;
  };
  recorder.start(1000);  
  btn.textContent = "stop recording";
  btn.onclick = (evt) => recorder.stop();
  // force recording at least 5 seconds
  btn.disabled = true;
  setTimeout(()=>  btn.disabled = false, 5000);
};

function drawToCanvas() {
  ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0);
  if( recording ) {
    setTimeout(drawToCanvas, 40); // ~25FPS
  }
}
function exportVid( data ) {
  const output = document.createElement("video");
  output.controls = true;
  output.src = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(data));
  btn.replaceWith(output);
  video.pause();
}
```

```css
video { max-width: 49vw; max-height: 100vh }
```

```html
<button id="btn">start recording</button>
```

However this API is not available everywhere yet, and it's quite buggy. For instance in current Firefox, it will stop the audio of the captured video, but hopefully they'll fix it soon enough.

Comment: Hi, awesome answer!  I tried to play with capturing the audiotrack of the video but had an issue when I came to pausing the video (whilst still recording the canvas stream).  The video paused fine however the audio just carried on playing)